# Multiple SharePoint display templates with paging results the other one without click functionality

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, paging, display-templates

I have multiple search display templates in SharePoint on the same page. If one of them have paging enabled (requirment) the other(s) lose their click events on new page rendered by clicking on 'next page'.

I have tried different solutions and the only workaround I have been able to come up with is reloading the page on paging click. I refuse to impliment this workaround.

Please see attached Template & Item display templates:

```html
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>
    <title>Document List Main No Title (Hide) 2</title>

    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
        <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
        <mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
        <mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">This is the default Control Display Template that will list the items. It does not allow the user to page through items.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
        <mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106601</mso:ContentTypeId>
        <mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#Content Web Parts;#</mso:TargetControlType>
        <mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
    <mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">http://v02vestasp02/_catalogs/masterpage/JSE/Display%20Templates/Content%20Web%20Parts/Document_List_Main_No_Title_Hide2.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
    </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
        </xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Control_ListWithPaging">

<!--#_ 
if (!$isNull(ctx.ClientControl) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl.shouldRenderControl) && !ctx.ClientControl.shouldRenderControl()) {
    return "";
}
ctx.ListDataJSONGroupsKey = "ResultTables";
var $noResults = Srch.ContentBySearch.getControlTemplateEncodedNoResultsMessage(ctx.ClientControl);
var isRollupPageInDisplayMode = Srch.ContentBySearch.isRollupPage(ctx.ClientControl) && !Srch.U.isPageInEditMode();
var noResultsClassName = isRollupPageInDisplayMode ? "ms-attractMode ms-uppercase ms-alignCenter" : "ms-srch-result-noResults";
var ListRenderRenderWrapper = function(itemRenderResult, inCtx, tpl) {
    var iStr = [];
    iStr.push('<li>');
    iStr.push(itemRenderResult);
    iStr.push('</li>');
    return iStr.join('');
}
ctx['ItemRenderWrapper'] = ListRenderRenderWrapper;
_#-->
    <ul class="cbs-List">

<!--#_
var showPaging = ctx.ClientControl.get_showPaging();
if(showPaging) {
    var pagingInfo = ctx.ClientControl.get_pagingInfo();
    if(!$isEmptyArray(pagingInfo)) {
        var getPagingImageClassName = function(buttonClassNamePrefix, isNext, isEnabled) {
            var className = buttonClassNamePrefix;
            className += (isNext && !Srch.U.isRTL()) || (!isNext && Srch.U.isRTL()) ? "right" : "left";
            if(!$isNull(isEnabled) && isEnabled == false) {
                className += "-disabled";
            }
            return className;
        }
        var getPagingContainerClassName = function(buttonClassNamePrefix, isEnabled) {
            var className = buttonClassNamePrefix;
            className += isEnabled ? "enabled" : "disabled";
            return className;
        }
        var firstPage = pagingInfo[0];
        var lastPage = pagingInfo[pagingInfo.length - 1];
        var hasNextPage = lastPage.pageNumber == -2;
        var hasPreviousPage = firstPage.pageNumber == -1;
        var buttonClassNamePrefix = "ms-promlink-button-";
        var nextPageContainerClassName = getPagingContainerClassName(buttonClassNamePrefix, hasNextPage);
        var previousPageContainerClassName = getPagingContainerClassName(buttonClassNamePrefix, hasPreviousPage);
        var nextPageImageClassName = getPagingImageClassName(buttonClassNamePrefix, true, hasNextPage);
        var previousPageImageClassName = getPagingImageClassName(buttonClassNamePrefix, false, hasPreviousPage);
_#-->
        <li class="ms-promlink-header">
            <span class="ms-promlink-headerNav">
                <a class="ms-commandLink ms-promlink-button _#= $htmlEncode(previousPageContainerClassName) =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(firstPage.title) =#_" href="#" onclick='$getClientControl(this).page(_#= $htmlEncode(firstPage.startItem) =#_);return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event);'>
                    <span class="ms-promlink-button-image">
                        <img class="_#= $htmlEncode(previousPageImageClassName) =#_" alt="_#= $htmlEncode(firstPage.title) =#_" src="_#= $urlHtmlEncode(GetThemedImageUrl('spcommon.png')) =#_">
                    </span>
                </a>

                <span class="ms-promlink-button-inner"></span>

<!--#_
        // Show the paging numbers
        for (var i = 0; i < pagingInfo.length; i++) {
            var pi = pagingInfo[i];
            if(!$isNull(pi)) {
                if (pi.pageNumber !== -1 && pi.pageNumber !== -2) {
                    var pageLinkId = "PageLink_" + pi.pageNumber;
                    // Check if it is the current selected page
                    if (pi.startItem === -1) {
_#-->
                    <strong>_#= $htmlEncode(pi.pageNumber) =#_</strong>
<!--#_
                    } else {
_#-->
                    <a id="_#= $htmlEncode(pageLinkId) =#_" href="#" title="_#= $htmlEncode(pi.title) =#_" onclick="$getClientControl(this).page(_#= $htmlEncode(pi.startItem) =#_);return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event);">_#= $htmlEncode(pi.pageNumber) =#_</a>
<!--#_
                    }
                }
            }
        }
_#-->

                <span class="ms-promlink-button-inner"></span>

                <a class="ms-commandLink ms-promlink-button _#= $htmlEncode(nextPageContainerClassName) =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(lastPage.title) =#_" href="#" onclick='$getClientControl(this).page(_#= $htmlEncode(lastPage.startItem) =#_);return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event);'>
                    <span class="ms-promlink-button-image">
                        <img class="_#= $htmlEncode(nextPageImageClassName) =#_" alt="_#= $htmlEncode(lastPage.title) =#_" src="_#= $urlHtmlEncode(GetThemedImageUrl('spcommon.png')) =#_">
                    </span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </li>
<!--#_
    }
}
_#-->

            _#= ctx.RenderGroups(ctx) =#_
        </ul>
<!--#_
if (ctx.ClientControl.get_shouldShowNoResultMessage()) {
_#-->
        <div class="_#= noResultsClassName =#_">_#= $noResults =#_</div>
<!--#_
}
_#-->

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>
    <title>JSE Item Document</title>

    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <xml>
            <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
                <mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
                <mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">                    Title{Title}:Title,
                    Path{Path}:Path,
                    FileExtension{FileExtension}:FileExtension</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
                <mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">This Item Display Template will show a 100x100 picture of the item on the left. The title and the default item description will display to the right of the picture with an additional line that is available for a custom managed property.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
                <mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
                <mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#Content Web Parts;#</mso:TargetControlType>
            <mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">http://v02vestasp02/_catalogs/masterpage/JSE/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/JSE_Item_Document.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:CrawlerXSLFile msdt:dt="string"></mso:CrawlerXSLFile>
<mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
        </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <!--
            Warning: Do not try to add HTML to this section. Only the contents of the first <div>
            inside the <body> tag will be used while executing Display Template code. Any HTML that
            you add to this section will NOT become part of your Display Template.
    -->
    <script>
        $includeLanguageScript( this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Language Files/{Locale}/CustomStrings.js" );
    </script>

    <!--
        Use the div below to author your Display Template. Here are some things to keep in mind:
        * Surround any JavaScript logic as shown below using a "pound underscore" (#_ ... _#) token
        inside a comment.

        * Use the values assigned to your variables using an "underscore pound equals"
        (_#= ... =#_) token.
    -->

    <div id="JSE_Item_Document">
        <!--#_
        var title = $getItemValue(ctx, "Title");
        var path = $getItemValue(ctx, "Path");
        var i = Srch.U.getIconUrlByFileExtension(ctx.CurrentItem);
                                var docID = ctx.CurrentItem.DocId;

                                function CheckDocID() {
                                                if (document.getElementById(ctx.CurrentItem.DocId) != null){
                                                                docID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                                                }
                                                
                                                if (document.getElementById(docID) != null){
                                                                docID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                                                }
                                }
                                
                                CheckDocID();
                                
        title.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);

                                AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function () { 
                                                function registerClickEvents(){
                                                                var ExpBorderShow = 'EbS';
                                                                $('#' + docID).click(function (e) {
                                                                                var $ShowDetailButton_clicked = $(this);
                                                                                var $ShowDetail_PrevSibling = $(this).prev();
                                                                                var $ShowDetail_DocLink = $(this).prev().children().first();
                                                                                var pHeight = $(this).parent().height();
                                                                                if ($ShowDetail_PrevSibling.hasClass(ExpBorderShow) &&
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.hasClass('Active')) {
                                                                                                var $Target = $(e.currentTarget);
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.removeClass('Active');
                                                                                                $ShowDetail_DocLink.css({
                                                                                                                'white-space': 'nowrap'
                                                                                                });
                                                                                                $ShowDetail_PrevSibling.css({
                                                                                                                'height': '20px'
                                                                                                });
                                                                                                if (pHeight >= 17) {
                                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.parent().animate({
                                                                                                                                height: '20px'
                                                                                                                });
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.removeClass("glyphicon-minus-sign");
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.addClass("glyphicon-plus-sign");
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.prev().toggleClass(ExpBorderShow);
                                                                                }
                                                                                else {
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.toggleClass('Active');
                                                                                                $ShowDetail_DocLink.css({
                                                                                                                'white-space': 'normal'
                                                                                                });
                                                                                                var h = $ShowDetail_DocLink.html();
                                                                                                if (pHeight <= 17 && h.length <= 44) {
                                                                                                                $ShowDetail_PrevSibling.css({
                                                                                                                                'height': '55px'
                                                                                                                });
                                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.parent().animate({
                                                                                                                                height: '55px'
                                                                                                                });
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                else {
                                                                                                                $ShowDetail_PrevSibling.css({
                                                                                                                                'height': '64px'
                                                                                                                });
                                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.parent().animate({
                                                                                                                                height: '64px'
                                                                                                                });
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.removeClass("glyphicon-plus-sign");
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.addClass("glyphicon-minus-sign");
                                                                                                $ShowDetailButton_clicked.prev().toggleClass(ExpBorderShow);
                                                                                }
                                                                });
                                                }
                                                
                                                setTimeout(registerClickEvents, 1500);
                                });
                                
        _#-->
        <div class="read__more__info__documents--c">
            <div class="read__more__info__documents--i">
                <img width="16" height="16" border="0" class="left" src="_#= i =#_" />
            </div>
            <div class="read__more__info__documents--a">
                <a class="read__more__info__documents" style="white-space : nowrap;" target="_blank" href="_#= path =#_">_#=  title =#_</a>
            </div>
                                                <div class="read__more__info__documents--s  glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"  style="font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';" id="_#= docID =#_"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript Jquery you can capture the page click event and write your logic there.

or you can customize the pager template and write your logic.

You can check the https://github.com/estruyf/DisplayTemplates link for the ref.